# Why I'm getting different results in C# and Python

Tags: python, c#, cryptography

I'm struggling to encode a string to SHA-256 with a specific key.
There is a python code that is used a reference.
The problem is that I cannot achieve the same result in C#.

```
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib

# Base64 encoded key (get it with /hook/{hookId}/key request)
webhook_key_base64 = 'JcyVhjHCvHQwufz+IHXolyqHgEc5MoayBfParl6Guoc='

# notification parameters
data = '643|1|IN|+79165238345|13353941550'

webhook_key = base64.b64decode(s))
print(hmac.new(webhook_key, data.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest())
```

C#

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var key = "JcyVhjHCvHQwufz+IHXolyqHgEc5MoayBfParl6Guoc=";
        var message = "643|1|IN|+79165238345|13353941550";

        var decodedKey = Base64Decode(key);
        var result = HmacSha256Digest(message, decodedKey);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string HmacSha256Digest(string message, string secret)
    {
        var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
        var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        var cryptographer = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
        var bytes = cryptographer.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }

    private static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: When you say you "cannot get the same result", what exactly is different? Did you try tracing through each program to see where the results diverge? Do you know which one (if either) is correct?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel pyton is the correct one, pyton outputs **76687ffe5c516c793faa46fafba0994e7ca7a6d735966e0e0c0b65eaa43bdca0** while C# **4417784269b2d590b5099d447829e8f70a05ee4e0d8ce3949286a6886b289b1f**

Comment: Okay, so the next thing is to check whether `decodedKey`, `keyBytes` etc. get the correct values corresponding to the Python program.

Comment: In `HmacSha256Digest()` replace the line `var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);` with `var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secret);` and when calling `HmacSha256Digest()` just pass the Base64 encoded key (`JcyV...uoc=`) as 2nd parameter (the call `var decodedKey = Base64Decode(key);` and the method `Base64Decode(key)` are not needed).

Comment: @Topaco Thanks! it worked! how can I mark your reply as answer?